# Faster way to copy a region from a bitmap in C

Tags: c, graphics, bitmap

I am using the following way to copy a region from a bitmap in rgb565 pixel format:

```c
void bmpcpy(size_t left, size_t top, size_t right, size_t bottom) {
    size_t index = 0;
    
    do {
        do {
            bmpCopy[index] = bmpSrc[(top * BMP_WIDTH) + left];
            index++;
        } while (++left < right);
    } while (++top < bottom);
}
```

Is there a faster way to do the copy?

Comment: You could do the `top * BMP_WIDTH` multiplication in the outer loop, but the optimizer may already take care of this. You also could use `memcpy` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

There might be faster ways using `memcpy` or accelerated graphics APIs, but first notice that your code is flawed:

- `bmpCopy` and `bmpSrc` are not defined, it is unlikely they should be global variables.
- `bmpCopy` is assumed to have a straddle value of `right - left`, not necessarily correct because of alignment constraints.
- `left` is not reset for each row.
- the width and height of the region are assumed to be non zero.

Depending on the type of `bmpSrc`, the parity and amplitude of `width` and the alignment of the source and destination pointers, it might be more efficient to copy multiple pixels at a time using a larger type.